# Send e-mails from a server, preventing from being blocked by anti-spam

Tags: server, dns, mail, smtp

I have a domain that points to server A. There is an 'a' entry in the DNS table of this server pointing to a server B. My website visitors will see the page hosted in the server B, not A. MX entries are pointing to gmail (google apps). When I use the PHP mail function to dispatch messages from server B, am I at risk of being blocked by antispam filter? If yes, how can I solve it?

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu. As the title says, this site is about Ubuntu, so this question is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are always at risk of being blacklisted (it sometimes even happens to gmail, hotmail & cie). However, to mitigate the risk, add server B's IP to the SPF entry for the domain, and look into setting up DKIM to certify the origin of the emails.